# dateformatter not showing right time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 y-axes and would like to plot time in the second y-axis according to 24 hrs format. below is the code but in the graph, the times come as 00:00:00. Only the second y-axis plot needs to be checked. the bar chart is plotted correctly with the corresponding score.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

rc('mathtext', default='regular')
 
# Creating dataset
x = Trend1['Date']
SleepDisturbance = Trend1['DisturbancesCount']
Movements = Trend1['AverageMovementCount']
Duration = Trend1['DurationInNumbers']


# Creating figure
#fig = plt.figure()
w=0.5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10)) 

# Plotting dataset_2
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, SleepDisturbance, label='Sleep Disturbance')
ax.bar(x, Movements, label='Average Movment')
 
# Creating Twin axes for dataset_1
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, Duration, '-r', label='Sleep duration')


# Adding title
plt.title('Sleep Disturbnace and Avergae movment vs. Sleep Duration',
          fontweight="bold")
 
# Adding legend
ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=20)
ax2.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=20)
 
# adding grid
ax.grid()
 
# Adding labels
ax.set_xlabel("Date",fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel("Counts", fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_ylabel("Sleep Duration", fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
 
# Setting Y limits
#ax2.set_ylim(0, 35, ymin=None, ymax=None)

ax.set_ylim(0, 15)

hh_mm_ss = DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
#ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hh_mm_ss)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(hh_mm_ss)

# Show plot
plt.savefig('SleepDisturbance and Average Movement vs. Sleep Duration.png',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Below is the output graph

[image]

Comment: How does your data (in particular for the y2-axis) look like? I suppose you somehow mix a "duration" format with a real date format (which has day, month, year as well)

Comment: Can you see the graph in the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pDUX.png

Comment: The time in the y-axis s is about sleep duration daily.

Comment: Please, post a sample of your data. Especially `Duration`. Else we can't know why this happens, and how to correct it. What is the return of `Trend1.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: Trend1 = {'Date': ['2022-10-19', '2022-10-20', '2022-10-21', '2022-10-22'],
        'DisturbancesCount': [2, 2, 3, 2], 'AverageMovementCount':[5,0,1,1],'DurationIn Number':[11:58:00,10:20:00,10:02:00,13:25:00]}

Comment: Matplotlib dates are in days since 1970-01-01.  If your durations are in seconds, so to make work, you should divide by duration / (24*3600) to get in units of days.

Comment: The duration is already calculated. I need to just adjust the tick in the second y-axis so it follows 24 hrs format. Do i need to add another column for 24 hour time